# Cufon clash with Nivo - replaced fonts in nivo HTML captions dissapear

Tags: javascript, styles, cufon, nivo-slider

Hope you can help me with this:

So, I have Nivo slider working fine and I built in some HTML captions in the support way.
Then I styed the HTML caption with h1 and h2 tags.
Then I implement cufon to replace h1 and h2 with a non-standard font.
Then, the nivo captions break - behaviour is a little unpredicatable but mainly the styled portions of the caption dissapper.

Any one seen/solved this before?

There is a lot of code associated with this and I dont want to bloat this post so let me know what the relevant parts are if you want to see examples.

Firstly, here are my javascript calls from the head section of my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.img.preload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hint.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nivoslider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/captify/captify.tiny.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
<!-- //////// Cufon - font Replacement ////////  -->
<script src="js/cufon/cufon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/cufon/bebas-neue.cufonfonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        Cufon.replace('h1, h3, h4, h5, #main_menu li a'); // Works without a selector engine
</script>
```

Thanks for any/all help.

Phil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cufon actually is outdated solution. It works really bad on dynamic sites. Mostly all browsers on the market are able to use CSS to show custom fonts. You can convert font and get CSS you need here http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator.

Comment: Looks good. Read some info yesterday that led me to believe that font-face was not well supported. What I am reading today suggests the opposite. I'll let you know if this is a solution.